# Oracle Unknown Character

Tags: oracle, replace

I have a script,

```
UPPER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(mbr.mbr_first_name) || ' ' || TRIM(mbr.mbr_last_name), '[-+"=;:,<>?\/.~`!@#$%^&*()_\-|{}[]]*',''), CHR(9), ' '), CHR(10), ' '), CHR(13), ' '))
```

where it basically removes special characters (as much as possible) and remains only the alphabet and numeric.

But after generation, I still get this (�) black diamond with white question mark.

Is there a way to include this in the regexp_replace or to identify the CHR() value for me to remove this kind of characters

Comment: `select dump(mbr.mbr_first_name), dump(mbr.mbr_last_name) from yourtable` to get the raw values. Sounds like you're having character set issues though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
regexp_replace(TRIM(mbr.mbr_first_name) || ' ' || TRIM(mbr.mbr_last_name),'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]')
```

Comment: thanks ! I need to review more regarding regular expressions.